# Need to display name in a dialogbox

Tags: android

```
case DIALOG_ID:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        EditText edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        Appendable name=edittext.getText();
        builder.setMessage(name + " Certificate saved successfully! Would like to add another Certificate?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                SaveData.this.finish();
          }
        })
```

In `builder.setMessage` i entered a string called **name** when i entered the name in the emulator in the first time its coming on dialog box but when i change the name on emulator to someother name the name which i entered first is coming it is not changing to the second name

**How can I do this? any help for me?**

Comment: what name do you want to display? Are you trying to pick a string from `textbox` and display it in the message?

Comment: i want to display a name there, which i will enter in the edittext on screen 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a String variable and store the text from the edittext ::

```
EditText edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_for_name);
String name=edittext.getText();
```

and then :

```
builder.setMessage(name+ " Certificate saved successfully. Would you like to add another certificate?")
```

Comment: i have to write the text in the emulator which is used to ask me to type the name, if we keep R.id.textname the default text will be appeared but i dont need that

Comment: so you want an EditText to appear before the dialog or you already have placed it somewhere?

Comment: i want an edittext to appear which i will type before the dialog box was clicked

Comment: so you have the edittext on the layout from which the dialogbox appears.., then I guess it should work.

Comment: i tried it but it is opening the default message which i entered in the edittext it is not taking the message which i entered manually on the emulator